Shopify Customizer Shows Code Working, But Isn't Working in Any Browser | Does Shopify Cache My Code?
I'm currently developing a custom Shopify theme and have encountered an issue that I'm hoping someone can help me resolve. I've added some Custom Liquids to my theme, and everything looks perfect in the Shopify theme customizer. However, when I view the site in any browser (I've tested Chrome, Firefox, and Safari), the changes are not reflected.
Additionally, I've noticed that even when I make the custom liquid empty, some parts of my code (which I suspect are cached) are still being displayed on the live site. This leads me to believe that there might be some caching mechanism at play on Shopify's servers.
This issue is causing major problems as I can't reliably update my site, and as a junior software developer new to Shopify, I'm not sure where the mistake might be. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.
I've tried using different browsers, incognito mode, and clearing my local cache, but nothing works. Even using different devices doesn't show me any traces.

You need to clear shopify's cache. This has nothing to do with browser cache - reference

@DarkBee Your reference actually only shows me how to delete my Chrome cache in detail but i don't get the Shopify part - please explain it to me.
thank you!

The only thing I can find quickly is this discussion

@DarkBee I was able to solve my problem, thanks for your help!
For anyone seeing this in the future:
I actually troubleshooted and found out that the Liquid code worked when I used the exact same code and pasted it into another custom Liquid template.
Don't ask me how—I can only wonder about it. It might be that it detects a new section and processes it, but sometimes won't update because the cache is not able to detect it or something. Anyway, I'm happy it works for me! :)
